Redirection www to non-www on Nginx gives me 400 bad request
I'm trying to redirect all www to non-www domain address. I have installed my LetsEncrypt SSL for non-www domain. non-www domains are working fine. I have configured www to non-www redirection on my Nginx running on Ubuntu server. I'm getting 400 bad request errors on www domains. On Windows Firefox and Mac Safari browser, http://www.examplesite.com will redirect to https://www.examplesite.com and it says it's a suspicious domain and I need to add exception to proceed. It looks like these two browsers are looking for SSL certificate for www.examplesite.com instead of examplesite.com. When I click on add exception and access https www.examplesite.com, I get a 400 bad request page from Nginx.
This problem doesn't happen on Chrome, Opera, Edge browsers. Only the two browsers get the redirection bug. What should I do to fix the bug on Safari and Windows Firefox? The domain is from Godaddy. It looks like Android Firefox and Chrome browsers don't experience this bug either.
Here are my Nginx configs:
/etc/nginx/conf.d/redirect.conf
server {

server_name www.examplesite.com;

rewrite ^/(.*)$ ``https://examplesite.com/$1`` permanent;

}

/etc/nginx/sites-available/examplesite
server {

server_name xxx.xx.xxx.xxx examplesite.com www.examplesite.com;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

location /static/ {

root /home/ubuntu/examplesite;

}

location / {

include proxy_params;

proxy_pass ``http://unix``:/run/gunicorn.sock;

}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/examplesite.com/fullchain.pem; # man>

ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/examplesite.com/privkey.pem; # m>

include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot

ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {

if ($host = examplesite.com) {

return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

} # managed by Certbot

if ($host = www.examplesite.com) {

return 301 https://examplesite.com$request_uri;

}

listen 80;

server_name xxx.xx.xxx.xxx examplesite.com www.examplesite.com;

return 404; # managed by Certbot

}

I tried tweaking them a lot but I couldn't find a solution

Please add output of nginx -T to the question so we can see full nginx configuration.

@Tero Kilkanen, I solved this issue. The problem was that I forgot to add www.examplesite.com domain in Django's allowed host settings. Also, I had to get LetsEncrypt certificate that works for both examplesite.com and www.examplesite.com. I got the one that only works for examplesite.com

I solved this problem. I found that I forgot to add www.examplesite.com to ALLOWED_HOST on Django's settings.py. I had only examplesite.com in ALLOWED_HOST.
